# Number of Basic Operations - Grade School Multiplication Algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I am currently taking an online course and am confused by this question regarding the Number of Basic Operations.

Problem: Count the number of these basic operations performed as a function of the number n of digits in the input

```
Input: Two n-digit numbers (The size of the input is the number of digits in the numbers.)
Output: the product of x * y
Basic Operation: Add or Multiply 2 Single-Digit Numbers
```

Example:

```
  5678
x 1234
--------
  22712 <= 2n Operations(Per Row)
 170340
1135600
5678000
--------- n Rows
7006652
```

Final Answer 2n^2

For the first line where 4 is being multiplied by each number in (5678) I count 4 operations:

```
1) 4*8
2) 4*7
3) 4*6
4) 4*5
```

So if n is the digits. N=4.

Now 2n = 8 -- which doesn't make any sense to me. Shouldn't it just be n?

So for each line the operation is suppose to be 2n Operations.  What does this exactly mean.
Is n=4 (since the amount of digits in the number is 4?)If n is 4 the total amount of basic operations for this would be (32). This doesn't make much sense to me.

I understand if we are taking the 4 in 1234 and multiplying it by each digit in 5678 we are performing 4 operations.  Why are we making that 2n? Is it because we are multiplying 5678 by 4 so they are also included in the total amount of operations? In my mind this seems like we are 'counting' operations twice and only performing them 1x.

If anyone can help clear up some of my thoughts I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $n$ is the number of digits.  In each row, you are multiplying a single digit (for the first row, the $4$) by the $n$ digits of the other number (the $5678$).  You also have to do additions for the carries.  In fact, you know there are no more than $n-2$ of these-there is no carry into the ones place and no product for the last carry to add to, but we can ignore the $2$ when compared with $n$.  That is where each row costs $2n$ operations.  Then since you have $n$ rows, to fill in all the rows above the final sum takes $2n^2$ operations.  They have ignored all the additions that are required for the final product.  For each row (after the first) you might have $n+1$ (consider it $n$) digits to add and as many as $n-1$ (consider it $n$) carries, for $2n$ operations.  With $n-1$ (consider $n$) rows to add, that is another $2n^2$ operations, for a total of $4n^2$

Comment: I thought they had left off the adding at the very end--that was puzzling me... :)

Comment: In each row, you are multiplying a single digit (for the first row, the 4) by the n digits of the other number (the 5678). If we were taking the very first row and first row only, we say it is 2n, We are multiply 1 number (4) by the top numbers, so it is (4*8), (4*7), (4*6), (4*5). This is 4 operations. So if we n is the digits we have 4 digits, 2(4) = 8 operations.  When I try implementing 2n, and 2n^2 and certain steps of the problem, I it never calculates the proper number of operations. How is 2n working on that first row? Thank you for your answer, it has been helpful!

Comment: In the first row of the example, you also have three additions for carries.  The $2$ carried from $4*5$ has to get added to the $4$ that comes from $4*6$ and so on.  That is where the other operations come from.  More accurately, it is only $2n-1$, but for problems like this we only consider the leading term.

Answer (score 2):

@HelloWorld

I am too late to answer this question.

Imagine a calculator. When you say 2+3 in a calculator, it is a single instruction. Similarly, 2*3 is also an instruction. So, every operation is an instruction to CPU, whether it may be sum or multiplication or division. In UG%, while working on 8086 processor, I saw vividly how every operation (instruction), a processor performs. You can also, spend some time on any processors.

In our case, algorithms care about these instructions, because every basic operation we perform in this algorithm is taken as an instruction by CPU. We are here to calculate the maximum number of basic operations (instruction) our CPU needs to perform for producing this partial product 4*5678.

5678
*1234

Lets see the **instructions of a CPU**, for our algorithm (only **partial product**):

4*5678

1. 4*8--->32, HOLD 2 & CARRY 3
2. 4*7--->28,
3. 28+3-->31, HOLD 1 & CARRY 3
4. 4*6--->24
5. 24+3-->27, HOLD 7 & CARRY 2
6. 4*5--->20
7. 20+2-->22, HOLD 2 & CARRY 2
8. 2 & 2 -->22712

If you observe, 2, 7, 1, & 2 are values we (CPU) held. But, we ignore the last 2 of 22, comes from CARRY 2. Remember the CARRY elements are 3, 3, 2, 2. Generally, we assume 3, 3, 2 and ignore 2.

2233 (carry elements)
 5678
  *4
------>
22712

So, value of the partial product is **22712**---basic number of operations required for this 8 which is <=2n. No, it is not 7.

<=2n, which is, in any given case, what ever value 'n' holds, the worst possible operations required (instructions) for producing this output (partial product) is always <=2n!!

Comment: Thank you @Shiva Shinde! I wish you were my math teacher! :)

Comment: Thanks for such kind words :)